# C#: Return current web path with http/https prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

When using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority` I can get the current host site, eg: localhost:8084.

Is it possible to get the 'full' host name, like: 'http://localhost:8084'?

For some implementations it will be http and other will be https and I need to create a URL based on the site address.

Comment: what does the `url` return?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host Note the difference between a local debugging environment and a production environment, in production environment you will get http or https and name of your host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection` to check if http or https.

Also please note that using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme` and`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` you can extract that information.